# align the loader at the center of the screen

Tags: html, css

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <style>
         .loader {   
         border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
         border-radius: 50%;
         border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
         width: 120px;
         height: 120px;
         -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite; /* Safari */
         animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
         }
         @-webkit-keyframes spin {
         0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
         100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
         }
         @keyframes spin {
         0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
         100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h2>How To Create A Loader</h2>
      <div class="loader"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

I am not able to align the loader at the center of the screen.
I have tried putting `align:center` in the loader class but that did not work.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

Comment: `align:center` does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Use flex box it would be simple and no extra css.

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```

You can study about flex box for further details, [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) and [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Flexbox would be "extra CSS" in itself.

Comment: much less than negative margins, and all other hacks. The purpose it solved without any such stuff.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <style>
         body {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          align-items: center;
          justify-content: center;
          height: 100vh;
         }
         .loader {   
           border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
           border-radius: 50%;
           border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
           width: 120px;
           height: 120px;
           -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite; /* Safari */
           animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
           }
           @-webkit-keyframes spin {
           0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
           100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
           }
           @keyframes spin {
           0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
           100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h2>How To Create A Loader</h2>
      <div class="loader"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

Welcome to Stack Overflow, Himanshu.

You can use the `margin` property to center the loader on the screen. The margin property sets the margins for an element (i.e. how far to the top, right, bottom and/or left an item is in relation to another on the DOM). If you supply `auto` to `margin-left` and `margin-right`, the loader will be positioned on the center of the screen.

```css
.loader {
    border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite; /* Safari */
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

A shortened version would be `margin: 0 auto 0 auto;`.